# Strange Glitch For Loop Inflating Views

Tags: android, for-loop, layout-inflater

I am trying to take a string (which is formatted HTML) and split it at every double enter. I know that before and after a double enter will be a p block tag, and I'm using a for loop to split it in this way. Here is my code

```
for(String s : rawHTML.split("\\n\\n")){
        View newView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.commentandunder, baseView, true);
        LinearLayout underneath = (LinearLayout) newView.findViewById(R.id.inside);
        TextView comm = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.commentLine);

        Log.v("Slide", "Should be " + s );
        Log.v("Slide", "Currently is "+ comm.getText());
        comm.setText(Html.fromHtml(s) );
```

Expected behavior from this is every "Currently is" in the log should be blank. If there are two or more p blocks, though, when I setText, it overwrites the previous text.

For example, I have a string

```
<p>Test</p>\n\n<p>Hello</p>
```

I should be seeing two TextViews like so

```
[Test]

[Hello]
```

Instead, I see this

```
[Hello]

[]
```

I am really stumped and can't figure out this strange issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet shoud work for you.

```
   View newView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.commentandunder, baseView, true);
   LinearLayout underneath = (LinearLayout) newView.findViewById(R.id.inside);
   TextView comm = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.commentLine);

   Log.v("Slide", "Should be " + s );
   Log.v("Slide", "Currently is "+ comm.getText());
   for(String s : rawHTML.split("\\n\\n")){
        comm.append(Html.fromHtml(s) );
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm actually trying to make a new TextView per p block, not appending the data into a TextView